# Efficiency Curve of Buck Regulator

Tags: buck, switching-regulator

Below is the efficiency curve for the TI TPS53513([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps53513.pdf)). Can someone explain what causes this characteristic efficiency curve? It seems to be similar to the one for other regulators as well. Why is the curve parabolic with a peak efficiency? Why is there a "discontinuity" in the curve at the low current ratings around 750mA where the curve jumps up and then down?

[image]

Comment: Not a SMPS expert, but my guess is that is where it switches over to continuous conduction mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-monotonic behavior appears in curves that have auto-skip mode enabled, so that's probably the culprit.

The efficiency of any SMPS regulator is zero at very low current, because the circuitry takes some power to operate.

It also will drop at high currents, as the switch conduction losses and I^2R losses in the inductor increase.

At a level in the middle, where the designer has optimized things, you'll get a maximum efficiency. For a given circuit or chip that optimum can be moved around a bit (sometimes a lot, if it's just a controller chip) by using different inductors or different MOSFETs (if that's an option).

Answer (score 1):

As you know, efficiency is what you get out for what you put in. eff = out/in. The quiescent current dominates at the low end. This is the power it takes to operate the regulator circuitry even under no load. Under no load, the regulator has 0% efficiency. At the upper end, pass transistor on resistance, increasing diode forward drop, and other losses due to approaching operating limits takes over and drags down efficiency. The jumps might be because the regulator switches operating modes due to trying to be more efficient at lower loads. This regulator has "Auto-Skipping Eco-mode."