# Efficiency of a switching regulator

Tags: switching-regulator

I have a 24V power supply line which I would like to transform to 5V (<1A) in order to supply my chips. Voltage regulators would waste a lot of energy in this range. I looked at some datasheets of such switching regulators e.g. [TSR1-2450](https://docs.rs-online.com/4483/A700000007055169.pdf). On page 1 it is stated that an efficiency of 92% can be achieved.

How is the energy loss calculated?

I would understand it that way: Regulation from 24V to 5V@1A results in 5W maximal output. With 92% efficiency the circuit would need

> 5W*1.08 = 5.4W

Comment: 5W / 0.92 actually, so a little bit over 5.4W.

Comment: The data sheet says *Efficiency up to 92%* - so expect less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.

$$ P_{IN} = \frac {P_{OUT}} {eff} = \frac 5 {0.92} = 5.43 \ \text W $$

Be aware that the efficiency will drop off somewhat at lower loads.

Comment: so the loss follows a curve (similar to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149218/efficiency-curve-of-buck-regulator)? Since the datasheet is rather short I can assume, that the 92% is measured a the best point in the curve.

Comment: I'd say that marketing would go for the peak figure, so yes.

Comment: My circuit operates at 700mA. As long as the 1A are guaranteed I can\ must live with the losses.